# Error when i send FromData to java - Angular 13

Tags: angular

applicationservice.ts.

```
aggiungiApplicazione(appForm: FormData): Observable<Applicazione> {
  return this.http.post<Applicazione>(`http://localhost:8080/Gestionale/api/applicazione/aggiunta`, appForm, {headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }});
}
```

component.ts

```
const appFormData = new FormData();

Object.keys(this.appForm).map((key) => {
  appFormData.append(key, this.appForm[key].value);
  // console.log(appFormData);
})


_aggiungiApplicazione(appData: FormData) {
this.applicazioneService.aggiungiApplicazione(appData).subscribe((app: Applicazione) => {
  console.log(app);
  timer(2000).toPromise().then(() => {
    this.display = false;
    this._getApplicazioni();
  })
});
```

}

And this is the Java Service

```
@POST
@Path("aggiunta")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Applicazione add(Applicazione a) {
    JpaDaoFactory.getDaoFactory().save(a);
    return a;
}
```

And this is the error I get when I try to add the application.

> **ERROR**
> **Type Status** Report

> **Message** Bad Request

> **Description** The server cannot or will not process the >request due to something that is perceived to be a client >error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request >message framing, or deceptive request routing).

If I try to remove the header I go into error 415

Comment: Why are you using FormData with the header type "application/json"?

Comment: What should i use? I have the same login system and it doesn't give me any problems

Comment: Maybe if you are not working with File Upload, try to use a regular js object and send requests.

Comment: >Type Status Report

>Message Unsupported Media Type

>Description The origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload >is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource.

I got this without the application/json
And I'm just sending a string

Comment: const appFormData = {};

Object.keys(this.appForm).map((key) => {
  appFormData[key] = this.appForm[key].value;
})
and pass this object with application/json header and see what happens.

Comment: I got the NullPointerException in java with this type of using

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

1- You are not passing the `appFormData` const which holds the value of the FormData to the endpoint. You only declare that `appData` is of type  `FormData` and then you pass this argument to the endpoint method from the service here:  `_aggiungiApplicazione(appData: FormData) {}`

Meaning the file payload is not included.

2- You need `multipart/form-data` with the right `--boundray` set by the browser by default in your request header. This will imply that you need to override the behaviour of your Global `HttpInterceptor` (if you use any) by defaulting to `HttpBackend`.

Comment: I'm sending the appFromData, i forgot to enter it, but i'm passing it